# Checking if a collection element exists in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, exists, user-defined-types

I create a simple type:

```
create or replace TYPE SIMPLE_TYPE AS OBJECT (ID NUMBER(38), NAME VARCHAR2(20));
```

Simple test:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE ObjectList IS TABLE OF SIMPLE_TYPE;
   tmp SIMPLE_TYPE := SIMPLE_TYPE(1, 'a');
   o ObjectList := new ObjectList(SIMPLE_TYPE(2, 'a'), SIMPLE_TYPE(3, 'a'));
BEGIN
   IF tmp.EXISTS(tmp) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('OK, exists.');
   END IF;
END;
```

I get an exception: PLS-00302: component 'EXISTS' must be declared

But this example work:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE NumList IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
   n NumList := NumList(1,3,5,7);
BEGIN
   n.DELETE(2);
   IF n.EXISTS(1) THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('OK, element #1 exists.');
   END IF;
   IF n.EXISTS(3) = FALSE THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('OK, element #2 has been deleted.');
   END IF;
   IF n.EXISTS(99) = FALSE THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('OK, element #99 does not exist at all.');
   END IF;
END;
```

Is it possible to implement EXISTS method in SIMPLE_TYPE type?

Comment: Are you sure you want `tmp.EXISTS`, not `o.EXISTS`? `tmp` is scalar even after you corrected its type. It's not a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tmp SIMPLE_TYPEE := SIMPLE_TYPE(1, 'a');

…

IF tmp.EXISTS(tmp) THEN
```

You declare `tmp` as `SIMPLE_TYPE`, not `ObjectList`.

`SIMPLE_TYPE` is scalar type, not a collection.

Probably you wanted to check `o.EXISTS` instead (which is an `ObjectList`)?

**Update:**

`EXISTS` when applied to a collection takes an integer index as an argument and checks if the element with this index exists (not its value).

To check that `SIMPLE_TYPE(1, 'a')` exists in your table, you should so the following:

Create `ObjectList` in a dictionary:

```
CREATE TYPE ObjectList IS TABLE OF SIMPLE_TYPE;
```

Issue the `SELECT` query:

```
DECLARE
        tmp SIMPLE_TYPE := SIMPLE_TYPE(1, 'a');
        o ObjectList := new ObjectList(SIMPLE_TYPE(2, 'a'), SIMPLE_TYPE(3, 'a'));
        myid INT;
BEGIN
        SELECT  1
        INTO    myid
        FROM    TABLE(o) q
        WHERE   SIMPLE_TYPE(q.id, q.name) = tmp
                AND rownum = 1;
        IF (myid = 1) THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('OK, exists.');
        END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Additionally we must serve NO_DATA_FOUND exception. Thanks for hint!

Comment: EXISTS when applied to a collection takes an integer index as an argument - and I am getting "ORA-01426: numeric overflow" because integer type is not enough for my collection elements

Answer (score 9):

As the [documentation states](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CIHIEBJC), `EXISTS(`) tests for the existence of a numbered entry in a collection.  That is, `array.exists(3)` asserts that the third element of `array` is populated.

What you are trying to do in your first example is test whether the instance `tmp` matches an element in `ObjectList`.  From 10g onwards we can do this using the `MEMBER OF` syntax.  Unfortunately, in order to make that work we have to declare a `MAP` method, which is rather clunky and would get rather annoying if the object has a lot of attributes.

```
SQL> create or replace type simple_type as object
  2       ( id number
  3         , name varchar2(30)
  4         , map member function compare return varchar2);
  5  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace type body simple_type as
  2       map member function compare return varchar2
  3       is
  4          return_value integer;
  5       begin
  6          return to_char(id, '0000000')||name;
  7       end compare;
  8  end;
  9  /

Type body created.

SQL>
```

Running the example...

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2      type objectlist is table of simple_type;
  3      tmp simple_type := simple_type(1, 'a');
  4      o objectlist := new objectlist(simple_type(2, 'a'), simple_type(3, 'a'));
  5  begin
  6      if tmp MEMBER OF o then
  7          dbms_output.put_line('ok, exists.');
  8      else
  9          dbms_output.put_line('search me');
 10      end if;
 11  end;
 12  /
search me

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: `MEMBER OF` .. this is a hint changed my life!  AWESOME ! Thanks !